# RHEL iSCSI on FreeNAS

Tags: redhat, storage-area-network, iscsi, truenas

I am able to mount a iSCSI SAN drive onto multiple RHEL Servers, but when I make changes to the files on SAN, they are not evident on the other servers sharing the same drive.
Am I missing something?

Looking for replies!
Cheers,
Anshuman

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have a filesystem installed on that iSCSI LUN that is designed to handle multi-mounts like you have there, this is entirely expected. iSCSI is a block-sharing protocol, not a file-sharing protocol, and it's up to the filesystem to handle things like file-locking, maintaining a coherent directory and file index, and flushed writes.

[OCFS2](http://oss.oracle.com/projects/ocfs2/) is one such filesystem, as is RedHat's [GFS2](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Global_File_System_2/ch-overview-GFS2.html). Something like ext4, btrfs, or xfs are not.

Comment: Thanks! Can we create a gfs2 file system just like we do for ext4 while discovering the iSCSI for the first time ie. using mkfs command??

Comment: @Anshuman It's much more complicated then that. GFS2 (the docs are linked) can only really be used inside of a RedHat cluster, and leverages clustered-LVM for volume management. It's more of a stack than a filesystem.

Comment: However OCFS2 is really simple to set up and run (at least on Debian, but I suppose it's about the same for RH).

Answer (score 2):

iscsi itself does not support concurrent access to the same lun without causing corruption, unless you have a clustering filesystem. are you sure that your setup is even supported by freenas? since iscsi lun is a block device like a hard drive so you cannot realy have it in multiple client servers. nfs allows shared access, however.

Comment: FreeNAS did allow me to share the drive among many rhel servers. But I guess they are not in con-current mode. Once U re-start each server, can U see the modified drive contents!

Comment: without something like a clustering filesystem, the behavior will be undefined and unsafe. even though it is allowed by freenas, it may not work as you would like it to.